# Which artifact represents spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security, spring-webflux

When I read this CVE https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-34034 it says that it affects spring security.
And on spring official website they talk about this CVE that it affects spring security: https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34034

I am not a developer, so I am not familiar with spring and its different projects, but I tried to search on maven online to see the spring security artifact but I got lot of results (see screenshot below)

[image]

Why I am doing so? because I want to know which component exeactly is affected by the CVE.

I was expecting to have a specific component that is affected by this CVE (eg: spring-security-core artifact) but there are lot of variations of spring security, and again I am not a developer and no idea what is the difference between each.
Furthermore, if that is affecting spring security, does that mean that if I am usign spring boot or spring framework then I am not affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, all of the artifacts are spring security.

Spring eco system is modular, meaning that you only pull in what is needed for your specific application.

### core

The base package that is always needed for all applications that want to use spring security (always needed).

### web

if you want to secure web related endpoints like REST, WebSockets etc.

### config

if you want to be able to configure your security (is basically always needed)

### crypto

says what it is contains crypto related functions algorithms, handling certificates etc. etc.

### test

contains all the testing tools to be able to write unit tests and other types of tests for spring security.

### Spring framework vs Spring boot

Spring started out like a basic framework that handled *dependency injection* in *servlet containers* like *tomcat*, *jetty* etc.

So it was basically just a library. That you can use in your application and then you deploy your application into a server.

The spring created *spring boot* which took the framework and embedded a server into the package so you could get an entire application including a server in one lean package.

So before boot, only an application that needed to be deployed on a server.

With boot, you get the server packaged into your application basically.

`Framework` are the fundamental packages that spring is based upon. For instance `spring-framework-core`. Then they use that packaged and built `spring boot` by including a server in the package (very simplified). Then if you want to have rest endpoints you include for instance `spring-web`. And if you want security you include `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-web`.

Instead of pulling in packages manually spring created `starters` for instance `spring-security-starter` which will pull in the necessary dependencies for you.

Comment: and to answer your most likely follow up questions, no i dont know where you should look to find the vulnerability. And im sorry this is a Q&A site, we cant teach you how to setup a spring security application so that you can test out the vulnerability, that is not what stack overflow is about. For that i suggest you lookup some tutorials online.

Comment: But who said I am asking how to setup a spring security application? why question was as simple as when CVE mentions spring security which one is meant then ? probably there is something I am not aware of or I am understanding it in a different way because I'm not a developer. Anws thank you for the feedback and for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into same issue and I have found that this vulnerability affects the dependency spring-security-config ([more information here](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3h6f-g5f3-gc4w)). To know how it can affect your project, you need to analyze your project dependencies. The IntelliJ IDE has a Dependency Analyzer tool that helps a lot to identify that. In my case, there was 2 dependencies using spring-security-config. Then I just used the dependency management session to make them use the fixed version:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

There are also some tools like Snyk that can help to identify vulnerable dependencies, how they are introduced in your project and what are the fixed versions.

Comment: So it ony affects the spring-security-config? if I am using spring-security without the config one then I am on safe side right?

Comment: I don't think is is possible to use spring-security without spring-security-config. To be safe, I would recommend to analyze your dependencies and run some scan to identify vulnerabilities.